# Why does Test-Connection force enumeration of reparse points?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, directory-listing

I've noticed some behavior in PowerShell that I can't explain, but I'm hoping that someone else can.

If I want to build a list of file objects from drive `C:\`, and I want to ignore shortcut folders (reparse points) such as `C:\Documents and Settings\`. The following command works well:

```
$FileList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -Force -Attributes !ReparsePoint);
$FileList | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Documents and Settings*"};
```

The `Where-Object` command returns no files as expected, since `C:\Documents and Settings\` is a reparse point.

However, if I run the `Test-Connection` command first, then the `Get-ChildItem` command appears to ignore the `-Attributes !ReparsePoint` parameter, and it traverses `C:\Documents and Settings\`.

```
Test-Connection -Computer MyComputer;
$FileList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -Force -Attributes !ReparsePoint);
$FileList | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Documents and Settings*"};
```

In this case, the `Where-Object` command displays a lot of files. Note that the `Test-Connection` can be run against any computer, not just the local computer to exhibit this behavior.

I've duplicated this behavior on computers running PowerShell 4.0 and PowerShell 5.1. Can anyone please explain what's happening?

---

Additional note: To duplicate this behavior, please make sure that you are using an elevated instance of PowerShell (Run As Administrator). If you use a standard instance of PowerShell, you won't have permissions to view `C:\Documents and Settings\`.

Comment: What happens if you open a new instance of `powershell.exe` and run the first example twice (without `Test-Connection` in between)?

Comment: Good question, Mathias.  So I ran the first example (No Test-Connection) 3 times in a row within the same elevated PowerShell instance, and the Where-Object command comes up empty all 3 times as you would expect.  In other words, $FileList never contains any files from within the "C:\Documents and Settings" tree.

Comment: I submitted this issue as a potential bug here:  

https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/33480847-bug-test-connection-forces-enumeration-of-repars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the first issue where it seems to ignore the `-Attributes !ReparsePoint`, see my full SO answer with examples here: [How to prevent recursion through node_modules for gci script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56135415/2150063). The TLDR is that by adding the `-Recurse` parameter to `Get-ChildItem` means that it will iterate through **-all-** items **first** *then* it will apply the filtering. That means it will faithfully exclude Reparse Points i.e. the specific folder: `C:\Documents and Settings` but since it get's all items **first**, it will also return everything underneath that folder as well. e.g. `C:\Documents and Settings\desktop.ini` because that *isn't* a Reparse Point, it's a *document*. That's why you can't use the `-Recurse` parameter without additional directory level filtering if that is your intention.

The second issue, executing `Test-Connection` changes what `Get-ChildItem` returns, does seem like a bug, in the manner that, it looks like this is a case of PowerShell not "fully" elevating the user when the `Get-ChildItem` is first executed. But at the same time, this might be intentional by the PowerShell team to remove the case of unintended duplicate items being returned.

To investigate, let's open a new PowerShell prompt as Administrator. I will slightly change the code to include a  `-Depth 1` just to make it easier to run through the code without having to enumerate my whole `C:` drive ;-) but, it will still illustrate the issue:

```
$FileList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Depth 1 -Recurse -Force -Attributes !ReparsePoint);
$FileList | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Documents and Settings*"};
```

When I run this, the first clue to what is going on is the error message:

> Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is
>   denied.

This highlights the fact that even though we are running the PowerShell prompt as Administrator, we are not running in a manner "elevated" enough to access the hidden, reparse point, system folder, "Documents and Settings". We have to keep in mind that the "Documents and Settings" folder is meant as a cheap workaround for legacy (<s>bad coders</s> ;-) compatibility with Windows Vista etc. and is not meant for "daily" normal usage. And if we do use it, it may cause unintentional duplicate/recursive items to be returned. i.e.:

```
PS C:\> $FileList | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Documents and Settings*"};
PS C:\>
PS C:\> $FileList | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Users*"};


    Directory: C:\Users


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a-hs-       2018-09-15   1:31 AM            174 desktop.ini
```

We see that we got the contents of the Users folder, but due to the error earlier, we did not return the contents of the Documents and Settings folder. This is good and likely intentional because we did not get any duplicate items. We only got the "real" items on the "real" path.

If we run the `Test-Connection` command next, followed by the same command (with different variable names to eliminate confusion):

```
Test-Connection -Computer MyComputer;
$FileList2 = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Depth 1 -Recurse -Force -Attributes !ReparsePoint);
$FileList2 | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Documents and Settings*"};
```

We notice 2 things:

1. We do not get any Access Denied error messages.
2. We get more (duplicate) items:

.

```
PS C:\> $FileList2 | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Documents and Settings*"};    

    Directory: C:\Documents and Settings


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a-hs-       2018-09-15   1:31 AM            174 desktop.ini

PS C:\> $FileList2 | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Users*"};


    Directory: C:\Users


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a-hs-       2018-09-15   1:31 AM            174 desktop.ini
```

This, I would say, is unintentional. Returning the items from the Reparse Point path is not desired. If we were feeding this information into other script tasks, e.g. `Remove-Item`, then we may run into unintended issues.

Now, let's move on to investigate why a seemingly innocuous command, `Test-Connection`, would cause a different outcome. The earlier Access Denied error message gives me a lead that something around authentication seems to be causing the difference. Let's close the PowerShell prompt and re-open it. Let's re-run the same first command:

```
$FileList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Depth 1 -Recurse -Force -Attributes !ReparsePoint);
$FileList | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Documents and Settings*"};
```

And let's check our Credentials to make sure that we are running as Administrator:

```
PS C:\> $currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
PS C:\> $currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
True
```

Indeed, we are running the prompt as Administrator, so that's not the issue. Let's look more into the Identity:

```
PS C:\> $currentPrincipal.Identities


AuthenticationType : Kerberos
ImpersonationLevel : None
IsAuthenticated    : True
IsGuest            : False
IsSystem           : False
IsAnonymous        : False
Name               : Contoso\HAL9256
Owner              : S-1-5-32-544
....
Token              : 3076
....
```

From this, we can see the "well known" group `S-1-5-32-544` as administrators. Notice the Impersonation Level is "None". If we run the `Test-Connection` and the same commands:

```
Test-Connection -Computer D4700;
$FileList2 = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Depth 1 -Recurse -Force -Attributes !ReparsePoint);
$FileList2 | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Documents and Settings*"};
```

And get the principal object:

```
PS C:\> $currentPrincipal2 = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
PS C:\> $currentPrincipal2.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
True
```

This proves we are still running as administrator. Now let's look at the identity:

```
PS C:\> $currentPrincipal2.Identities


AuthenticationType : Kerberos
ImpersonationLevel : Impersonation
IsAuthenticated    : True
IsGuest            : False
IsSystem           : False
IsAnonymous        : False
Name               : Contoso\HAL9256
Owner              : S-1-5-32-544
....
Token              : 4500
....
```

This time we see that the Impersonation Level is `Impersonation`. From the [Impersonation Level Enum Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.tokenimpersonationlevel?view=netframework-4.8#fields):

> Impersonation 3
>
> The server process can impersonate the client's
>   security context on its local system. The server cannot impersonate
>   the client on remote systems.

When we did the `Test-Connection` it required a network resource on the local computer in order to perform the ping. In order to do this, it transparently elevated the prompt to `Impersonate` level from `None` (we can even see this happened because the Token Number changed). This has the side effect of allowing the `Get-ChildItem` to now have the elevated rights to access the system file Documents and Settings. i.e. like checking off "show hidden files" in File Explorer, and now allowing it to enumerate through the Reparse Point.

We can also observe that this is the cause when we remote into another machine:

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName RemoteMachine -Credential (Get-Credential) -Authentication Kerberos

[RemoteMachine]: PS C:\Users\HAL9256\Documents> $FileList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Depth 1 -Recurse -Force -Attributes !ReparsePoint);
[RemoteMachine]: PS C:\Users\HAL9256\Documents> $FileList | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -like "*Documents and Settings*"};


    Directory: C:\Documents and Settings


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a-hs-        7/16/2016   7:21 AM            174 desktop.ini


[RemoteMachine]: PS C:\Users\HAL9256\Documents>
[RemoteMachine]: PS C:\Users\HAL9256\Documents> $currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
[RemoteMachine]: PS C:\Users\HAL9256\Documents> $currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
True
[RemoteMachine]: PS C:\Users\HAL9256\Documents>
[RemoteMachine]: PS C:\Users\HAL9256\Documents> $currentPrincipal.Identities

AuthenticationType : Kerberos
ImpersonationLevel : Impersonation
IsAuthenticated    : True
IsGuest            : False
IsSystem           : False
IsAnonymous        : False
Name               : Contoso\HAL9256
Owner              : S-1-5-32-544
....
Token              : 4420
....
```

When we do this, we see that it returns Documents and Settings without needing `Test-Connection` to be executed first. Looking at the Principal, we see that the Impersonation Level is set to `Impersonation`.

Ultimately this tells us that the cause of this incongruity is the Impersonation Level setting. In order to access the hidden system file, and Reparse Point, we need the Impersonation Level set to at least `Impersonation`.

Comment: I know that this goes against the SO rules, but I just have to say thank you very much for going above and beyond with your THOROUGH answer!  Wow!  Good stuff!  

And if one of the SO moderators wants to give me demerit for writing a "thank you" comment, then so be it!

My hat is off to you HAL9256 for the taking the time to so thoroughly research an answer and write up such an easily digested summary.