# How to prevent recursion through node_modules for gci script

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I found this fantastic powershell script

```
gci -include bin,obj -recurse | remove-item -force -recurse
```

in a comment by [Chris J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130352/chris-j) on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924807/1121289)

I use this multiple times a day.

How do you prevent this from running through any node_modules folders if they exist or their children?

I've tried various versions of

```
gci -exclude node_modules -include bin,obj -recurse | remove-item -force -recurse
```

without success.

UPDATE:
After reading @HAL9256's informative answer i realized i failed to include an important requirement.  I run this script at the root of my git repo.  Therefore, it traverses multiple C# project folders removing the bin and obj folders for all of them.  This is only necessary because Visual Studio 2017 & 2019 solution clean doesnt remove everything and as we are in the process of converting from framework to standard/core there are artifacts that get left in the bin and/or obj folder after cleaning that causes things to break when transitioning (probably from core back to framework) a given project via a git branch change.

Comment: if you are running psv5.1, then - as i recall - the `-Exclude` and -Include` ONLY apply to file names, not to directories. so the usual way to get around that is to use an after-the-fact filter like `Where-Object` or `.Where()` to exclude the unwanted items.

Comment: it appears that is not entirely true, because the first script above uses -include with bin and obj which are directories.  It deletes all bin and obj folders.  the problem is that i don't want it to delete bin and obj folders within any node_modules folders.  how would i use Where-Object or .Where() to achieve that?

Comment: ah! that must be yet another difference in behavior with ps5.1 on win7. [*sigh ...*] ///// for the fitler >>> `$Collection | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -notmatch 'bin|obj'}` <<< should do the job. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

The root of this issue is the combination of a misuse of recursion combined with filtering. I will go through some examples to illustrate. First we should set up an example directory structure:

```
mkdir Temp
mkdir Temp\bin
mkdir Temp\obj
mkdir Temp\node_modules
mkdir Temp\node_modules\bin
mkdir Temp\node_modules\obj

Out-File .\Temp\Readme.md
Out-File .\Temp\bin\Readme.md
Out-File .\Temp\obj\Readme.md
Out-File .\Temp\node_modules\Readme.md
Out-File .\Temp\node_modules\bin\Readme.md
Out-File .\Temp\node_modules\obj\Readme.md

cd .\Temp\
```

Let's try some examples. I will pipe the contents of `Get-ChildItem` into a `Select-Object` to better illustrate what we are retrieving. First, a vanilla `Get-ChildItem`:

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-ChildItem | Select-Object FullName

FullName
--------
C:\Temp\bin
C:\Temp\node_modules
C:\Temp\obj
C:\Temp\Readme.md
```

This returns what we expect, equivalent to a `dir`. Now, let's try a `-Include` to only "Include" the `bin` folder.

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-ChildItem -Include bin | Select-Object FullName
PS C:\Temp>
```

Hmmm. It returned nothing... We thought that it would take the list of everything, and "only" include the bin folder. What it instead did is interpret the command as, `Get-ChildItem` of, "nothing", (because we didn't specify any files to get), and "Include" of the "nothing", the pattern `bin`. This makes sense, and is listed in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6#parameters) that "Include needs the Path parameter". Ok. Let's change it to actually get everything `*` *then* do an `-Include bin`, *then* we should get what we want... Right?

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-ChildItem * -Include bin | Select-Object FullName
PS C:\Temp>
```

Hu? I thought with the wildcard, it would include the `bin` folder right? Isn't that how it works?.... well not exactly. Let's change it to `-Include` a file instead of a directory:

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-ChildItem * -Include Readme.md | Select-Object FullName

FullName
--------
C:\Temp\Readme.md
```

So it looks like the explicit filtering, with a wildcard is for **files** and not *directories*. Then how does the original example, where we included directories work?... Well it's because `-Recurse` works differently. `-Recurse` changes what we get, it returns *everything* so the `Include` works:

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-ChildItem -Include bin -Recurse | Select-Object FullName

FullName
--------
C:\Temp\bin
C:\Temp\node_modules\bin
```

In this example, when we don't have to specify the wildcard `*` filter the `-Recurse` implicitly gets everything from the directory. Notice: it included directories that matched the name `bin`. Also, notice, it did not include files inside the directories.

Why example 1:

```
gci -include bin,obj -recurse | remove-item -force -recurse
```

Works is because the `Get-ChildItem` returns the directories, and the `Remove-Item` with the `-Force` and `-Recurse` takes care of removing the files.

To prove that nothing funky goes on, let's do an `-Exclude node_modules`:

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-ChildItem -Exclude node_modules -Recurse | Select-Object FullName

FullName
--------
C:\Temp\bin
C:\Temp\bin\Readme.md
C:\Temp\node_modules\bin
C:\Temp\node_modules\bin\Readme.md
C:\Temp\node_modules\obj
C:\Temp\node_modules\obj\Readme.md
C:\Temp\node_modules\Readme.md
C:\Temp\obj
C:\Temp\obj\Readme.md
C:\Temp\Readme.md
```

Well... that returned more than expected... but not. Notice that it did not return `C:\Temp\node_modules`. This is because `-Exclude node_modules` was correct. It excluded the folder specifically named: `node_modules`, and included everything else.

*This* is why the second example does not work:

```
gci -exclude node_modules -include bin,obj -recurse | remove-item -force -recurse
```

The exclusion filter will exclude the specific folder named `node_modules`, but, due to `-Recurse` will `-Include` any sub folder that matches `bin`, or `obj`. Which *of course*, `node_modules` has a ton of, and hence, doesn't work as we want.

So, if `-Include` doesn't work with directories, and `-Recurse` goes too deep, what will solve @cResults question? Well, instead of messing around with filters, why don't we just simply ask for the folders that we want like normal?

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-ChildItem bin,obj | Select-Object FullName

FullName
--------
C:\Temp\bin\Readme.md
C:\Temp\obj\Readme.md
```

Well this is ok, it returned the *contents* of the folders, just like the earlier example, the *child items* and not directories... Well what we *really* wanted was the *folder item* so instead of `Get-ChildItem` we use `Get-Item`:

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-Item bin,obj | Select-Object FullName

FullName
--------
C:\Temp\bin
C:\Temp\obj
```

Ah now, with the switch to `Get-Item` we get the folder, and not the child items inside the folder, which we can now use with `Remove-Item` which takes care of the rest:

```
Get-Item bin,obj | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: thank you for your thorough and informative explanation.  Your breakdown and illustration of the process has greatly improved my understanding of how the code i've been trusting actually works.  I've added a requirement to the question that i failed to include prior to reading your answer.  When i run the Get-Item as you describe, it throws saying bin doesnt exist, which at the root of my git repo it doesnt.  Thank you again for teaching us.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking, as I have just been, here is a complete solution.
Using the `Where-Object` that [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120021/how-to-prevent-recursion-through-node-modules-for-gci-script#comment98896554_56120021) suggested you can exclude the `node_modules` directories after the recurse.

`gci -include bin,obj -recurse | where-object {$_.FullName -notlike '*\node_modules*'} | remove-item -force -recurse`